# Using RegularExpressionValidator for numbers only in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

Visual Studio 2012, Asp.net, webforms.
Trying to control input into textbox, numbers only.  I have the following code:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
                 ControlToValidate="txtAcres"
                 ValidationExpression="^\d+"
                 Display="Static"
                 ErrorMessage="Only Numbers"
                 EnableClientScript="False" 
                 runat="server"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

but i am allowed to enter any text.  What am I missing?

Comment: Try: `ValidationExpression="^\d+$"`

Answer (score 14):

This checks first if textbox is blank and then it checks for numbers only.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbAccount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Checks if textbox is blank:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorAccount" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required" ControlToValidate="tbAccount" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Allows only numbers:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbAccount" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Only Numbers" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^\d+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code on **ASPX** Page. Use `^[1-9]\d$` in ValidationExpression property.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtstock" width="50" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Numeric Only" ControlToValidate="txtstock"
      ValidationExpression="^[1-9]\d$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `true` for `EnableClientScript` property.

```
 EnableClientScript="true"
```

> Use the EnableClientScript property to specify whether client-side
>   validation is enabled. Validation controls always perform validation
>   on the server. They also have complete client-side implementation that
>   allows DHTML-supported browsers (such as Microsoft Internet Explorer
>   4.0 and later) to perform validation on the client. Client-side validation enhances the validation process by checking user input
>   before it is sent to the server. This allows errors to be detected on
>   the client before the form is submitted, avoiding the round trip of
>   information necessary for server-side validation, [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx)

Comment: By changing EnableClientScript to true i receive the error: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).

Comment: If you are using framework 4.5 then this may be useful, When targeting .NET 4.5 we enable Unobtrusive Validation by default. You need to have jQuery in your project and have something like this in Global.asax to register jQuery properly, http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735928/in-asp-net-web-application-visual-basic-the-requiredfieldvalidator-doest-work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^(0|[1-9]\d*)$`
Good Sucessful !